# Populate datamodel with zero-to-many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My problem is populating a datamodel with a "sub-datamodel"
In this case I got many products. Each product are categorized, but some products are not categorized at all. A product can even be linked to several categories. Not sure how I'm supposed to do this.
This is what I got so far:

Database, tablestructure:

```
tProduct
   ProductId int
   ProductName varchar(250)
tCategory
   CategoryId int
   CategoryName varchar(250)
tLinkProductCategory
   ProductId int
   CategoryId int
```

Datamodel:

```
public class ProductModel
{
   public int ProductId;
   public string ProductName
   public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> Categories;
}
public class CategoryModel
{
   public int CategoryId;
   public string CategoryName;
}
```

Query:

```
public IQueryable<ProductModel> GetProductQuery()
{
   var query = from product in DataContext.tProduct
          //left join
          from linkProductCategory in DataContext.tLinkProductCategory.Where(e => e.ProductId == product.ProductId).DefaultIfEmpty()
          //left join
          from category in DataContext.tCategory.Where(e => e.CategoryId == linkProductCategory.CategoryId).DefaultIfEmpty()

          select new ProductModel() {
             ProductName = product.Name
             Categories = //something missing here
          };
   return query;
}
```

**UPDATE**
This approach did the trick:

```
..
select new ProductModel() {
   ProductName = product.ProductName,
   Categories = product.tLinkProductCategory.Select(c => new CategoryModel
   {
      CategoryID = c.tCategory.CategoryId,
      CategoryName = c.tCategory.CategoryName
   }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
from product in DataContext.tProduct
select new ProductModel()
           {
             ProductName = product.ProductName,
             Categories = (from category in DataContext.tCategory
                           join linkProductCategory in DataContext.tLinkProductCategory on category.CategoryId equals linkProductCategory.CategoryId
                           where linkProductCategory.ProductId == product.ProductId
                           select category
                           ).ToList()
           };
```